# Apple ios5 iMessage read and write

Tags: xcode, ios5

With the new iOS5 is there a way that you can read incoming iMessages and write new iMessages using a custom app?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that would be possible. Allowing third party apps to read users' messages would be a severe privacy violation.

Comment: I would like to read the iMessage and send it over bluetooth to another device..i know this can be done via SMS but is there absolutely no way to read an iMessage from some buffer or area?

Comment: There is no public API for doing that in my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Your app can't read them, but it can allow the user to write and send one using [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668).

Note that it will use SMS when the receiver isn't using iMessage.