# Is it possible to send picture with text with iMessage from my App with iOS 6.1?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, imessage

Someone already asked it in 2011: [iPhone:send image+text  to iMessage  from my own app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445197/iphonesend-imagetext-to-imessage-from-my-own-app), but maybe there exists now a way of doing it. Does someone know some news about this topic? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is still no way to send multimedia via `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

`MFMessageComposeViewController` is the only authorised way to access the compose screen from 'Messages', and [the documentation still clearly says](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668):

> Sending multimedia messages with this class is not supported

The camera icon typically found in the Messages app does not exist in this standalone view controller, meaning any form of multimedia (bar text) cannot be sent.